# Can I write my partial differential equation in this form?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Can I expand the first equation into the second equation or is that not mathematically correct? If I can expand the equation, but I have done it wrong, could you please show me how to expand the equation correctly?

$\qquad\tau =  \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}\left (D(x,t)\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} (x,t)\right)$

$\qquad\tau =  \dfrac{\partial D }{\partial x}(x,t)\dfrac{\partial \rho }{\partial x}(x,t) + D(x,t)\dfrac{\partial^2 \rho }{\partial x^2}(x,t)$

Comment: Yep you can do it that way and it looks like you've done it correctly. You're just applying the usual product rule in this instance and that does work with partial derivatives too.

Comment: If you’re going to work in ODEs or PDEs, or CFD for that matter, build your confidence in application of the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you both so much. Are there any good sources to read up on chain rule, and other derivative properties?